# What are the advantages of top 20 universities over top 70s for CS PhD in USA?

Tags: phd, united-states, ranking

I am a Computer Science M.Sc. Student in a university in a developing country. I am planning to apply for PhD this year. Actually my main reasons to not continue my PhD here, are the issues related to my country economics and infrastructures. Poor dorm conditions, no funded PhD, unstable internet, no proper study place in university are some of them where decrease the quality and contributions of a PhD student and I think that those issues will be solved by the migration to USA itself and is not related to the rank of the destination university. to make my question clear, actually **I want to know what are the benefits of a top 20 university in USA saying, Caltech over a top 70 university saying, Oregon State University .** I can imagine one or two like the strong advisor and peers but I can't think more. please note that I am not asking about the after-graduation job perspective, I mean What is the effects on the quality and contributions of a PhD student to study in a top-20 instead of a top-70 university.

P.S: if it matters ranks are according to the **US News** portal.