# What are the diffrence between the quality of top 20 universities PhD programs over top 70s for USA?

Tags: phd, united-states, ranking

I  am a Computer Science M.Sc. Student in a university in a developing country. I am planning to apply for PhD this year. Actually my main reasons to not continue my PhD here, are the issues related to my country economics and infrastructures. Poor dorm conditions, no funded PhD, unstable internet, no proper study place in university are some of them where decrease the quality and contributions of a PhD student and I think that those issues will be solved by the migration to USA itself and is not related to the rank of the destination university. to make my question clear, actually **I want to know what are the benefits of a top 20 university in USA saying, Caltech over a top 70 university saying, Oregon State University .please note that I am not asking about the after-graduation job perspective, I mean What are the effects on the quality and contributions of a PhD student that studies in a top-20 instead of a top-70 university.**

P.S: if it matters ranks are according to the US News portal.

Comment: The US News rankings are meaningless because (IIRC) they compare entire universities with one another, rather than trying to compare individual departments. Those two things come apart, often dramatically. Rutgers University in NJ isn't a particularly distinguished university in general, but it's perhaps the best philosophy department in the world, and certainly the best for some particular areas of philosophy.  It's good to go to a better-ranked department, and better-ranked places will have better infrastructure, as you mention, but look at departments, not universities.

Comment: @shane: There are more US News rankings than are dreamt of in your philosophy: http://grad-schools.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-graduate-schools/top-science-schools/computer-science-rankings.  I can't specifically speak for CS, but I am familiar with the math rankings and know they are compiled by asking a lot of mathematicians which departments have the best reputation.  In my opinion and experience, this is meaningful and in fact *the best way* to determine the rough classification of departments...according to their reputation.

Comment: You asked a [virtually identical question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/65471/73) earlier, which was closed as a duplicate. If you think this is not a dupe, please comment as to why not, but please refrain from simply reposting the question without change.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thanks for the tip, I didn't realize US News had started doing this. The methodology looks sound. To be clear, I'm not opposed to rankings, just *bad* rankings.

Comment: @eykanal Actually I have changed that post, i.e. that question is edited, but unfortunately SO has very weak process in reopening a duplicated question. so I asked a new question which is a preserved right for me as I know.

Comment: I can't ever believe that some one has read this paragraph:  ".please note that I am not asking about the after-graduation job perspective...." and then marked my question as duplication! Ha ha :D

Comment: I see your comment now. In that case, though, what *are* you asking? [US News published the factors they use when ranking schools](http://www.usnews.com/education/best-colleges/articles/how-us-news-calculated-the-rankings); reading through that will tell you what's different between high- and low-ranked universities. That's all public info; what else are you looking for?

Comment: The metrics expressed them may not directly effect the quality of a PhD student researches(or just simple quantify it as the quality of his papers!). factors like Student selectivity,  Retention, Undergraduate academic reputation or Graduation rate performance are nonsense to my question.